# Oracle Apex change text color based on derived column value in IG

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid in apex application which has 2 columns.

The query is as below:

The grid has 3 columns: CURRENT_KPI, NEW_KPI and RESULT.
As can be seen result column results from CURRENT_KPI-NEW_KPI.

```
select to_char(KPI_1,'999,999,999,999') CURRENT_KPI, 
       case when dept=1 
            then to_char(KPI_2,'999,999,999,999') 
            else to_char(KPI_3,'999,999,999,999') 
        end as NEW_KPI, 
       to_char( kpi_1 - case when dept=1 
                             then kpi_2
                             else kpi_3
                          end,
                 '999,999,999,999' ) result
from KPI_DATA;
```

I need to change text color of result column such that:

> If number is positive, i.e. 999,999,999 , text will be blue. If number
> is negative, i.e.  -999,999,999, text will be brown. If number is 0,
> text color will be red.

Apex version: 20.2

How can this be achieved?

EDIT: Options available in IG Actions menu operator:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use what Apex offers - **highlighting**.

- run the interactive grid
- go to Actions menu, select Format, select Highlight
- create as many of them as you want, e.g.

  - name it "blue"
  - highlight "row"
  - set "text color" to "blue" (#99CCFF)
  - condition type is "column"
  - column name is "result"
  - operator is "greater than"
  - value is "0"

Once you create them all, run the page and text will be painted in colors you chose.

Comment: Hi, in the IG Actions menu there is no operator with greater than option. I have edited my post with snapshot of options available

Comment: Even if i try it for value equal to 0, i.e. operator ëquals to"value is "0"- it doesn't work either

Comment: "greater than" is valid for **numbers**. Your RESULT is a **string** so you'll have to figure it out. Hint: leave it a number, but set its format mask in appropriate field in column's **Property palette**.